# set headers as vertical in Microsoft Excel 2013 using Genexus 3

Tags: excel, genexus

I am trying to create a report in Excel using genexus data. It is easy, I click on a button called "Create a report", then I collect data from Genexus data and I set them up into Excel file. But I want headers to be shown up as vertical headers with picked data from GENEXUS. I hope you understood me, I am a spanish speaker. Do I have to use Javascript?

Comment: Keep in mind there's a SO site in Spanish regularly reviewed by the Genexus community http://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I will. But there are better answers in english than spanish.

Comment: I'm aware of that... I'm just saying that if you need to ask, you can do it in Spanish also (or Portuguese)

Answer (score 1):

Setting vertical headers cannot be done using Excel Document API.

But you could create your Excel Document from an existing Excel Template that already has all the "styling" you need.

[Template property](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6991,Template%20Property)